# Poll: which are the "Cinderella" topics?

Tags: discussion, voting

We all have the feeling that every TikZ post, even the most trivial one, gets a lot of upvotes.

My question is: on the contrary, which are the topics that deserve more upvotes than the ones they usually get?

<sup>The poll results will be used by Herr Professor Paulinho van Duck in 4th third article on the TUGBoat (the 3rd is already in press). He reserves the right to not include an answer in his research because of moral scruples.</sup>

Comment: see https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/888155/average-answer-score-by-tag for some data -> I think it is actually not as bad as we perceive.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/950955/ has a little more data (with standard deviation). It would be interesting to see median values and percentiles (boxplot data) and could be instructive to exclude very highly-voted questions and answers (go-to duplicates) to get a more even picture of 'your average question and answer', but I could not get the SQL to disclose that info to me.

Comment: @moewe Ohh, nice query! Do you happen to know how to exclude tags that only have a few answers?

Comment: @samcarter Non clue at all, I'm afraid. I just found that query on SEDE and modified the sort order. It's all Greek to me and that query in particular is quite hard for me to understand.

Comment: @moewe Ah, seems we both use the same approach for SEDE :) I'll just download the data and filter myself.

Comment: I actually always felt that the statement "Ti*k*Z gives lots of upvotes" may not be entirely correct. And indeed, according to the data it does not. As far as I can see it only has the most posts, so if you look at a random post with many votes, there is a greater chance that it is Ti*k*Z than something more exotic. Another effect is that there are more users that read (and use) the Q & A with more popular tags, so these attract more upvotes.

Comment: @marmot Are you sure: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346695/how-can-we-draw-a-duck-in-order-to-create-a-tikzducks-package-and-store-it-in-c?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Look at [the posts sorted by reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) and check how long you need to scroll down to see a Ti*k*Z post.

Comment: I have the impression (but I may be wrong) that it is the simplest answers that are most voted for, regardless of the tag, TikZ or any other. This is because everyone, even those who do not use the package, fully understands both the question and the technical answer.

Comment: @AndréC Often the simplest are the most useful.

Comment: @CarLaTeX [useful and tikz free](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and also pineapple pizza free!

Comment: I an sure they are serving that in first class.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thank you for your comments. I think you could also transform them into an answer with some examples of posts or tags, if you like.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The SEDE queries suggested by samcarter (https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/888155/average-answer-score-by-tag) and me (https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/950955/) in the comments show the average answer score. The average, however, is very sensitive to outliers and therefore probably less useful to analyse 'your *average* question'. A more robust measure such as the median might be more useful.

`fun`, `cervantex`, `big-list`, `research` and `triskaidekaphobia` are amongst the top tags by average answer score. Not only are there very few questions with those tags, they are also not representative of the majority of questions on this site.

Many tags also have a small number of highly-voted questions. Some of these questions are about common pitfalls and therefore often linked, some have evolved to go-to duplicate questions, others are of very wide interest or just produce interesting, unexpected, or stunning output. Those questions are usually also not representative of the voting behaviour for that tag.

Based on the following query https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/951095/average-answer-score-by-tag that gives the number of answers for a given score and tag I came up  with the following crude R script (the data was downloaded to `tag-score-answercount.csv`). It analyses the 16 tags with more than 5000 answers (to keep things manageable)

```
sede <- read.csv("tag-score-answercount.csv")
tags <- unique(sede$TagName)
tags.anscount <- sapply(tags, function (s) sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==s]))

toptags <- tags[tags.anscount >= 5000]
toptags.anscount <- tags.anscount[tags.anscount >= 5000]

revectorise <- function(x, count){
  rep(x,count)
}

fd <- data.frame(tag=c(), score=c())

buildfakedata <- function(s){
  data.frame(tag=s, score=revectorise(sede$Score[sede$TagName==s], sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==s]))
}

for (s in toptags){
  fd <- rbind(fd, buildfakedata(s))
}

histlims <- c(min(fd$score), 20)
breaks <- seq(histlims[1], histlims[2])
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(4,4))
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1)
for (s in toptags){
  hist(fd$score[fd$tag==s & fd$score<=20],
       breaks=breaks, xlim=histlims, ylim=c(0,.23), freq=F,
       ylab=NULL, xlab=NULL, axes=FALSE, main=paste("Histogram for", s))
}
par(opar)

bp <- boxplot(score~tag, fd, outline=FALSE)
title("Answer score by tag")
abline(h=0,lty=3)
abline(h=median(fd$score))
abline(h=mean(fd$score), col="red")
means <- tapply(fd$score,fd$tag,mean)
points(means,col="red",pch=19)

scorecutoff <- 50
fdtrim <- fd[fd$score <= scorecutoff,]

boxplot(score~tag, fdtrim, outline=FALSE)
title(paste("'Typical' answer (score <=", toString(scorecutoff), ") score by tag", sep=""))
abline(h=0,lty=3)
abline(h=median(fdtrim$score))
abline(h=mean(fdtrim$score), col="green")
means <- tapply(fdtrim$score,fdtrim$tag,mean)
points(means,col="green",pch=19)
```

The histograms are chopped off at +20 (arbitrary cut-off) and -6 (the absolute minimum score in the 16 tags). They show the probability/relative frequency and all have the same bin sizes (intervals of one from -6 to 20) as well as the same y axis (from 0 to 0.24)

[image: 16 histograms for top tags]

Here `table-of-contents`, `floats` and `tables` show comparable poorer scores with very light tails and a high concentration on the lower bins. `symbols` and `math-mode` have heavier tails (i.e. a higher proportion for answers with higher score).

The following box plots show scores over all answers for a tag. The red dot marks the mean answer score for a tag, the red line shows the overall mean. The whiskers extend up to 1.5 times the IQR from the box.

[image: box plots over all answers]

The plots confirm the intuition we got from the histograms that `table-of-contents` and `floats` perform worse than the other tags. `symbols`, `math-mode`, `macros`, `fonts` and `tikz-pgf` show higher median scores.

As mentioned above, highly-scoring outliers can skew the results so that certain tags appear to perform better than they usually do. Since boxplots rely on more robust quantile measures, big changes are not expected if outliers are excluded, provided there are only a few. The following plots are restricted to answers with scores of no more than 50. This time the green colour shows the means.

As expected the mean goes down (after all the mean is very susceptible to outliers), but perhaps less expectedly there are subtle changes in the boxes for `biblatex`, `floats` and `fonts`. At least for `biblatex` that change seems to be down to the fact that the 0.75 quantile is just at the border between 5 and 6 (the full data set has the border at 0.747/0.748, the reduced set at 0.751/0.752, this difference of 0.004 comes down to about 25 answers on a total of 6242 answers) which means that removing even few high scoring answers (28 answers in this instance) can let the quantile drop. I haven't looked into the other tags, but I suspect similar effects.

[image: Box plots over 'typical' answers]

A word of warning: We are dealing with integer data whose overall distribution seems 'pretty close'. Mean and standard deviation are quite susceptible to outliers, but even the more robust measures of our box plots can't escape small side effects, so that differences of ±1 may well be due to edge effects rather than a stable underlying trend (see the changes in the plots for `biblatex` examined above). The median score over all tags is three, one additional vote can have quite the effect there. If one wants to compare specific tags, looking at the boxplots and histograms alone won't cut it.

---

Here is a slightly more sophisticated (but still naive) version of the script above. The interesting things are now packed up in functions, so they are easier to reuse.

The data still comes from https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/951095/average-answer-score-by-tag

```
sede <- read.csv("tag-score-answercount.csv")
tags <- unique(sede$TagName)
tags.anscount <- sapply(tags, function (s) sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==s]))

cycle.colours = c("blue", "red", "seagreen", "deeppink", "orange")

# concentrate on tags with more than cutoff.ansnum answers
cutoff.ansnum <- 2000
toptags <- tags[tags.anscount >= cutoff.ansnum]
toptags.anscount <- tags.anscount[tags.anscount >= cutoff.ansnum]


# This function plots the "tails" of the score distribution,
# i.e. the relative frequency of answers with score at least s
# input: scorevec  a vector of scores
#        sort      a TRUE/FALSE flag on whether to sort the tags
#                  by the tail frequency for the first score
plot.scoretails <- function(scorevec, sortby=NA){
  # no vectorisation here :-(
  a <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(toptags), ncol=length(scorevec))

  for (i in 1:length(toptags)){
    a[i,] <-
      sapply(scorevec,
             function(s) sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==toptags[i] & sede$Score>=s])/
               sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==toptags[i]]))
  }

  if (!is.na(sortby) & is.element(sortby, scorevec)){
    a.sort <- a[,match(sortby, scorevec)]

    toptags <- toptags[order(a.sort)]
    a <- a[order(a.sort),]
  }

  ylim = c(0,max(a))
  plot.colours <- rep_len(cycle.colours, length(scorevec))

  par(mar=c(9,4,4,1)+.1)
  magicoffset <- 0.028
  plot(a[,1], type="o", pch=19, col=plot.colours[1], ylim=ylim, xlim=c(1,(1+magicoffset)*length(toptags)),
       xaxt = "n", xlab=NA, ylab=expression(F(X>=s)), frame=F,
       main="Rel. frequency of answers with score at least s")
  for (i in 2:length(scorevec)){
    points(a[,i], type="o", pch=19, col=plot.colours[i])

  }
  text(length(toptags)+magicoffset*length(toptags), a[length(toptags),],
       labels=sapply(scorevec, function(s) as.expression(bquote(s==.(s)))), col=plot.colours)

  axis(1, at=1:length(toptags), labels=toptags, las=2)
}

plot.scoretails(c(3,4,5,6,10,20), sort=10)
plot.scoretails(c(5,7,10,12), sort=5)

plot.scoretails(c(8,10,15,18,20), sort=20)

plot.scoretails(c(80,100,250,200), sort=80)

# to make things easier for histograms and boxplots we reverse engineer a data frame
# with the data for each "answer"
revectorise <- function(x, count){
  rep(x,count)
}

fd <- data.frame(tag=c(), score=c())

buildfakedata <- function(s){
  data.frame(tag=s, score=revectorise(sede$Score[sede$TagName==s], sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==s]))
}

for (s in toptags){
  fd <- rbind(fd, buildfakedata(s))
}

# histograms are arbitrarily chopped at 20
histcutoff.right <- 20

histxlims <- c(min(fd$score), histcutoff.right)
breaks <- seq(histxlims[1], histxlims[2])
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(4,4))
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1)+0.1)
for (s in toptags){
  hist(fd$score[fd$tag==s & fd$score<=max(histxlims)],
       breaks=breaks, xlim=histxlims, freq=FALSE, ylim=c(0,.24),
       ylab=NULL, xlab=NULL, axes=FALSE,
       main=paste("Histogram for", s))
}
par(opar)

# Boxplots
plot.boxplot <- function(fd, ylim=NA, showMean=TRUE, showSD=FALSE, col="red", title="Answer score by tag"){
  par(mar=c(9,3,3,1)+.1)
  if (missing(ylim)){
    bp <- boxplot(score~tag, fd, outline=FALSE, las=2, frame=F)
  }
  else{
    bp <- boxplot(score~tag, fd, outline=FALSE, ylim=ylim, las=2, frame=F)
  }

  title(title)
  abline(h=0,lty=3)
  abline(h=median(fd$score), lwd=2)
  if (showMean){
    abline(h=mean(fd$score), col=col, lwd=2)
    means <- tapply(fd$score,fd$tag,mean)
    points(means,col=col,pch=19)
    if (showSD){
      sds <- tapply(fd$score,fd$tag,sd)
      points(means+sds,col=col,pch=1)
      points(means-sds,col=col,pch=1)
      abline(h=mean(fd$score)+sd(fd$score), col=col, lwd=1, lty=2)
      abline(h=mean(fd$score)-sd(fd$score), col=col, lwd=1, lty=2)
    }
  }
}

plot.boxplot(fd, ylim=c(-6,25), showMean=TRUE, col="red")


# we exclude outliers by considering only answers with score no more than 50
# the first plot verifies that this is not too bad,
# this should cover more than 90% of questions per tag
# for the more common tags even more than 97%
typcutoff <- 10
fdtrim <- fd[fd$score <= typcutoff,]

typfreq <- sapply(toptags,
                  function (s) sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==s & sede$Score<=typcutoff])/
                    sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==s]))

plot(typfreq, type="o", xaxt="n", xlab=NA, frame=F, ylab=NA)
title(paste("Rel. frequency of answers with score no more than", typcutoff))
axis(1, at=1:length(toptags), labels=toptags, las=2)


plot.boxplot(fdtrim, ylim=c(-6,25), showMean=TRUE, col="seagreen",
             title=paste("'Typical' answer (score <=", typcutoff, ") score by tag", sep=""))


# plot empirical distribution or survival function (tail probability) for list of tags
# restrict the plotted x range with xlim to see local behaviour
# ymin is usually 0, but for small x ranges it might be convenient to get auto-detect with ymin=NA
# survival plots (almost) the survival function F(X>=s) instead of the distribution function F(X<=s)
plot.ecdf <- function(tags, xlim=NA, ymin=0, survival=FALSE){
  if (missing(xlim)){
    xmin <- min(sede$Score[is.element(sede$TagName, tags)])
    xmax <- max(sede$Score[is.element(sede$TagName, tags)])
  }
  else{
    xmin = min(xlim)
    xmax = max(xlim)
  }

  xseq <- seq(xmin,xmax,1)

  plot.colours <- rep_len(cycle.colours, length(tags))

  a <- matrix(nrow=length(xseq), ncol=length(tags))

  if (survival){
    cdf.f <- function(x,i=i){
      sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==tags[i] & sede$Score>=x])/
        sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==tags[i]])
    }
  }
  else{
    cdf.f <- function(x,i=i){
      sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==tags[i] & sede$Score<=x])/
        sum(sede$AnswerCount[sede$TagName==tags[i]])
    }
  }


  for (i in seq_along(tags)){
    a[,i] <- sapply(xseq, function(x) cdf.f(x, i))
  }

  if (is.na(ymin)){
    ymin <- min(a)
  }
  ymax <- max(a)

  par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+.1)
  plot(xseq, a[,1], type="o", pch=19, ylim=c(ymin,ymax), col=plot.colours[1],
       xlab="Answer score", ylab="Rel. frequency")
  if (length(tags)>1){
    for (i in 2:length(tags)){
      points(xseq, a[,i], type="o", pch=19, col=plot.colours[i])
    }
  }

  if (survival){
    legpos <- "topright"
    title <- "Empirical survival function (tail probabilities): Score at least s"
  }
  else{
    legpos <- "bottomright"
    title <- "Empirical distribution function: Score less or equal than s"
  }
  title(title)
  legend(legpos, tags, pch=19, col=plot.colours, title="Tag", bty = "n")

}

plot.ecdf(c("cross-referencing", "lyx", "biblatex", "luatex", "tikz-pgf"), xlim=c(1,4), ymin=NA, survival=T)
plot.ecdf(c("cross-referencing", "lyx", "biblatex", "luatex", "tikz-pgf"), xlim=c(0,10), survival=T)
plot.ecdf(c("cross-referencing", "lyx", "biblatex", "luatex", "tikz-pgf"), xlim=c(0,20), survival=T)
plot.ecdf(c("cross-referencing", "lyx", "biblatex", "luatex", "tikz-pgf"), xlim=c(10,20), survival=T)
```

The script analyses more tags (here all tags with at least 2000 answers, but that can be modified in `cutoff.ansnum`).

The following plot shows the relative frequency of answers scoring at least s by tag. The list is sorted not alphabetically but by the relative frequency of answers scoring 10 or more (that's why the curve for s=10 has no bumps, while all other curves have ups and downs). The lines are just there because I found them easier on the eye than just points, but they serve no real purpose. In particular there should be no implication that the points on a curve somehow influence each other or should follow a particular shape.

[image: Rel. frequency of answers scoring at least s]

Again `symbols` scores quite well, but the absolute top tag here is `tex-core`. `lyx` (perhaps unsurprisingly), `bibliographies` and `tables` perform below average.

[image: Boxplots over all answers]

[image: Boxplots over 'typical' answers]

As mentioned above it might be quite interesting to compare several tags directly. The plot below shows the 'survival function' or 'tail probabilities' of scoring at least s. A higher probability/relative frequency would be better. For more detailed interpretations it would be necessary to compare the behaviour of these functions over several 'windows' of x/s ranges.

[image: Tag comparison]

Comment: Wow! What a detailed analysis!

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks a lot for your thorough analysis!

Comment: Now that I think about it the boxplots for `<=50` might actually be a bit of a red herring. It might be instructive to look at the means when we restrict ourselves to lower/more typical scores, but the boxplots shouldn't really change unless a tag has very high scores (in which case it would not be proper to throw out the high-scoring answers anyway) and most changes will be down to low-level edge effects (the fact that we usually only have steps of 1 in the quantiles).